# Cleaner Rspec spec_helper File and Instance Variables

Tags: rspec

I am looking to provide all my test files with some constants and am not sure of the very best way to do this using rspec. Would this way be best practice over declaring instance variables? Thank you!

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'app.rb')
require 'rack/test'

set :environment, :test
set :run, false
set :raise_errors, true
set :logging, false

def access_token
   "xxxxx"
end

def api_token
  "xxxxx"
end

def app
   Sinatra::Application
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

#no database debug messages
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

RSpec doesn't limit you in ways to define data for your specs. You can use regular methods, constants, local, instance or class variables, etc. It's really up to you to choose the most appropriate solution.

Apart from standard Ruby, RSpec also has support to explicitly [name the subject](http://betterspecs.org/#subject) and [collaborators in your tests](http://betterspecs.org/#let).

Personally, I use `subject(:app)` for the object under test, `let` for collaborators (mostly classes), local and instance variables inside `before` blocks or inside the specs for simple stuff like usernames and passwords and (factory) methods for setting up more complex objects.